# HTML5 Required property Just works with Save Button in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, c#-4.0

I am sorry in advance for a stupid question. I am working in asp.Net I used Required property of HTML5 for TextBox. When I just clicks on TestConnection button(which is server side. and Saving data in data base) this button click perfom required validation at all fields. But Mu need is to test validation only at Button Save.

Comment: you need to enable client side validation  in web config

Answer (score 0):

you can make `TestConnection` client side button and check validation by `jquery`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script> 

  <appSettings>
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

> you need to enable client side validation  in web config like above. try with it and bind those script with your project ,Hope it will help for you